# How to do Identity Pinning(iOS) and networkSecurityConfig(Android) for enabling SSL pinning on a React Native application

Tags: react-native, sslpinning

I am trying to implement SSL pinning in my React Native application. So far, most of the blogs talks about using react-native-ssl-pinning package. Recently came to hear that, instead of using a package the same can be achieved,

On iOS, you can use "Identity Pinning" (available iOS 14 and newer) to specify certificate hashes in your Info.plist file. This pins the certificate for both native and react-native network calls.

On Android, you can specify domain certificates in a networkSecurityConfig XML file. This also pins for native and react-native network calls.

If somebody know how this can be achieved, please share some details.

react-native-ssl-pinning is not being maintained, so a new approach would be the ideal choice.

Comment: AFAIK SSL pinning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) is deprecated. Why do you need this ?

Comment: The mobile app will be going into PENT testing and this is one critical item to be implemented mostly from security perspective